# Json Jackson List of List

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

Is this even possible?

I'm trying to get a set of coordinates for a chart and i'm returning a list of list.
i call the method with $.ajax and i get a syntax error , but when i call the method in a webpage i can get the results and then i validate them with JSONLint and says it's ok, then i use JSONLint with my localhost url and it says that theres a syntax error but i cant understand it, can anyone help me?

**The method**

```
@RequestMapping(value="graph1")
        public @ResponseBody JsonPack<List<GraphData>> graphAge_Weight0_36(@RequestParam(value="patient")int idPatient){

            List<Ageweight0To36Months> data = aw036Service.getAll("Ageweight0To36Months");
            List<List<GraphData>> allData = new ArrayList<List<GraphData>>();
            List<GraphData> list = new ArrayList<GraphData>();
            Ageweight0To36Months aux = new Ageweight0To36Months();
            GraphData singleD = new GraphData();
            Patient patient = patientService.getById(idPatient);
            String query = "FROM Consultation c where c.idPatient=" + idPatient;
            String gender = (patient.getSex().compareTo("masculino")) == 0? "M" : "F"; 

            for(Method m: aux.getClass().getMethods()){

                if(m.getName().startsWith("getP") && m.getParameterTypes().length == 0){
                    list = new ArrayList<GraphData>();
                    for(Ageweight0To36Months aw: data)
                    {   
                        System.out.println(aw.getGender() +","+gender);
                        if(aw.getGender().compareTo(gender) == 0){
                            try{
                                Object p =  m.invoke(aw);
                                singleD  = new GraphData(aw.getAgeInMonths(),Double.valueOf(p.toString()).doubleValue());
                                list.add(singleD);
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    allData.add(list);
                }
            }
```

**The response**

```
{"aaData":[[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":2.355451},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":2.799549},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":3.614688},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":4.342341},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":4.992898},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":5.575169},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":6.096775},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":6.56443},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":6.984123},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":7.361236},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":7.700624},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":8.006677},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":8.283365},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":8.534275},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":8.762649},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":8.971407},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":9.16318},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":9.340328},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":9.504964},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":9.658975},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":9.804039},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":9.941645},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":10.073105},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":10.199575},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":10.322062},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":10.441442},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":10.558473},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":10.673803},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":10.787982},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":10.901473},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":11.014664},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":11.12787},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":11.241348},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":11.355298},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":11.46988},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":11.58521},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":11.701371},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":11.759784}],[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":2.526904},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":2.964656},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":3.774849},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":4.503255},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":5.157412},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":5.744752},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":6.272175},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":6.745993},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":7.171952},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":7.555287},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":7.900755},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":8.212684},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":8.495},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":8.751264},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":8.984701},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":9.198222},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":9.394454},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":9.575757},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":9.744251},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":9.90183},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":10.050187},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":10.190823},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":10.32507},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":10.454102},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":10.578949},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":10.700513},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":10.819575},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":10.936812},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":11.052801},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":11.168034},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":11.282926},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":11.39782},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":11.513},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":11.628692},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":11.745079},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":11.8623},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":11.980456},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":12.03991}],[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":2.773802},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":3.20951},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":4.020561},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":4.754479},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":5.416803},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":6.013716},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":6.551379},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":7.035656},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":7.472021},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":7.865533},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":8.220839},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":8.542195},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":8.833486},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":9.098246},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":9.339688},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":9.560722},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":9.763982},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":9.95184},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":10.126434},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":10.28968},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":10.443295},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":10.588812},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":10.727592},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":10.860844},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":10.989635},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":11.114904},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":11.237473},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":11.358059},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":11.47728},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":11.59567},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":11.713683},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":11.831705},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":11.950054},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":12.068997},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":12.188748},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":12.309477},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":12.431315},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":12.492682}],[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":3.150611},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":3.597396},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":4.428873},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":5.183378},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":5.866806},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":6.484969},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":7.043627},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":7.548346},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":8.004399},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":8.416719},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":8.789882},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":9.12811},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":9.435279},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":9.714942},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":9.970338},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":10.204418},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":10.419863},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":10.619101},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":10.804329},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":10.977527},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":11.140475},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":11.294771},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":11.441847},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":11.582978},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":11.719299},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":11.851817},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":11.981419},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":12.108888},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":12.234907},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":12.360072},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":12.484898},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":12.609827},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":12.735234},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":12.861438},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":12.988699},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":13.117232},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":13.247207},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":13.312776}],[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":3.530203},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":4.003106},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":4.879525},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":5.672889},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":6.391392},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":7.041836},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":7.630425},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":8.162951},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":8.644832},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":9.08112},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":9.4765},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":9.835308},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":10.161536},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":10.458854},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":10.730626},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":10.979925},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":11.209555},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":11.422068},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":11.619777},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":11.804779},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":11.978966},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":12.144043},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":12.301541},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":12.45283},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":12.599135},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":12.741544},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":12.881023},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":13.018424},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":13.154497},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":13.289897},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":13.425194},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":13.560881},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":13.697379},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":13.835046},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":13.974182},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":14.115032},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":14.257796},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":14.329944}],[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":3.879077},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":4.387423},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":5.327328},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":6.175598},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":6.942217},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":7.635323},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":8.262033},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":8.828786},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":9.34149},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":9.805593},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":10.226124},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":10.607722},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":10.95466},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":11.270871},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":11.559963},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":11.825241},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":12.069725},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":12.29617},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":12.50708},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":12.704728},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":12.891168},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":13.068254},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":13.237653},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":13.400856},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":13.559197},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":13.71386},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":13.865896},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":14.01623},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":14.165672},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":14.314932},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":14.464622},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":14.61527},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":14.767324},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":14.921166},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":15.077109},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":15.235412},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":15.396279},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":15.477724}],[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":4.172493},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":4.718161},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":5.728153},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":6.638979},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":7.460702},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":8.202193},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":8.871384},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":9.475466},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":10.021014},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":10.514064},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":10.960172},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":11.36445},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":11.731602},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":12.065948},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":12.371453},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":12.651749},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":12.910152},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":13.149687},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":13.373106},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":13.582902},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":13.781331},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":13.970425},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":14.15201},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":14.327718},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":14.499004},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":14.667158},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":14.833316},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":14.998478},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":15.163512},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":15.329172},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":15.496103},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":15.664853},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":15.835883},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":16.009575},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":16.186239},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":16.366119},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":16.549405},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":16.642369}],[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":4.340293},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":4.91013},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":5.967102},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":6.921119},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":7.781401},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":8.556813},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":9.255615},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":9.885436},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":10.453314},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":10.965736},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":11.428676},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":11.847633},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":12.227661},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":12.573402},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":12.889108},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":13.17867},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":13.44564},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":13.693251},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":13.924442},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":14.141875},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":14.347954},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":14.544842},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":14.734482},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":14.918606},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":15.098756},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":15.276296},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":15.452424},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":15.628189},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":15.8045},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":15.982139},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":16.161769},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":16.34395},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":16.529146},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":16.71773},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":16.910002},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":17.106191},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":17.306461},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":17.408165}],[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"yCoordinate":4.446488},{"xCoordinate":0.5,"yCoordinate":5.032625},{"xCoordinate":1.5,"yCoordinate":6.121929},{"xCoordinate":2.5,"yCoordinate":7.10625},{"xCoordinate":3.5,"yCoordinate":7.993878},{"xCoordinate":4.5,"yCoordinate":8.793444},{"xCoordinate":5.5,"yCoordinate":9.513307},{"xCoordinate":6.5,"yCoordinate":10.16135},{"xCoordinate":7.5,"yCoordinate":10.744924},{"xCoordinate":8.5,"yCoordinate":11.270838},{"xCoordinate":9.5,"yCoordinate":11.745385},{"xCoordinate":10.5,"yCoordinate":12.174357},{"xCoordinate":11.5,"yCoordinate":12.563083},{"xCoordinate":12.5,"yCoordinate":12.91645},{"xCoordinate":13.5,"yCoordinate":13.238933},{"xCoordinate":14.5,"yCoordinate":13.534622},{"xCoordinate":15.5,"yCoordinate":13.807244},{"xCoordinate":16.5,"yCoordinate":14.060194},{"xCoordinate":17.5,"yCoordinate":14.296548},{"xCoordinate":18.5,"yCoordinate":14.519093},{"xCoordinate":19.5,"yCoordinate":14.730343},{"xCoordinate":20.5,"yCoordinate":14.932559},{"xCoordinate":21.5,"yCoordinate":15.127765},{"xCoordinate":22.5,"yCoordinate":15.31777},{"xCoordinate":23.5,"yCoordinate":15.504178},{"xCoordinate":24.5,"yCoordinate":15.688406},{"xCoordinate":25.5,"yCoordinate":15.871699},{"xCoordinate":26.5,"yCoordinate":16.055142},{"xCoordinate":27.5,"yCoordinate":16.239671},{"xCoordinate":28.5,"yCoordinate":16.42609},{"xCoordinate":29.5,"yCoordinate":16.615076},{"xCoordinate":30.5,"yCoordinate":16.807196},{"xCoordinate":31.5,"yCoordinate":17.002914},{"xCoordinate":32.5,"yCoordinate":17.202598},{"xCoordinate":33.5,"yCoordinate":17.406538},{"xCoordinate":34.5,"yCoordinate":17.614947},{"xCoordinate":35.5,"yCoordinate":17.827972},{"xCoordinate":36.0,"yCoordinate":17.936247}],[{"xCoordinate":27.01,"yCoordinate":60.0}]]}
```

**The error**

```
Parse error on line 1:

^
Expecting '{', '['
```

**Edit:**
I dont know if my javascript is wrong currently im using this:
 **The javascript**

```
function drawGraph(graph){
    var idPatient=$("#consultationPatientId").val();
    var patientName = $("#consultationPatientName").val();

    $.jqplot('divChart',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]); 

    var url;
    switch(graph){
        case 1:
            url = "./consultation/graph1";
            break;
            case 2:
                break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        break;
                        case 5:
                            break;
                            case 6:
                                break;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        data: { 'patient':idPatient },
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(response){
            console.log("algo");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });

}
```

The ajax method returns a error of syntax so, im unable to even read the response, an i wanted to asing it to a variable in the javascript.

so, reding the error a lot of times i think that maybe this might be the error, should'nt be {[{{ instead of {[[{ the oder?

```
{"aaData":[[{"xCoordinate":0.0,"y
```

**The Jquery ajax error**

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 4 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the JSON?  Can you expand or better explain where you are seeing the error?  If the JSON parses fine, then I would venture a guess that it's probably in your JavaScript, not the JSON.

Comment: i was unable to identify the error at first because the web page was rendering the answer and jsonlint dind't said anything when i copy/pasted the answer. but using the ajax error i got the message that the syntax was wrong.

Comment: Sweet.  Those sorts of errors can drive one made.  Happy coding!

Comment: ammm.... Thanks but even now i have been unable to solve this.

Comment: Isn't your aaData a list of lists?  If so, then `[[{` is right (`[` starts the first list, `[` starts the inner-list, `{` starts the object in the inner list).

Comment: Also, you can read the response in the browser's debug tools.  In Chrome hit F12.  I believe IE's Developer Tools is also accessible via F12.  In FireFox I think you have to install the FireBug addon.  I usually use Chrome, which lists communications on the Network tab.  Simply launch your site with Dev tools open and look for the AJAX request.  Click on it, and there should be a tab/view for seeing the raw Response with headers.  As far as the JSON you posted is concerned, I don't see anything wrong with it.